# What is a good datastore for very, schemaless wide rows?

Tags: database, bigdata

I'm looking for a datatore with the following characteristics.

- I'm storing information about Person objects
- A Person can have thousands of Attributes
- Not every Person has every attribute
- It should be column based, as queries typically touch a handful (under 10) attributes
- It should be schemaless, as I add new Attribute types on a regular basis
- Around 100GB data currently, will scale up to maybe 500GB-1TB

What's a good solution for storing this type of data?

Answer (score 0):

This question is maybe a little off-topic since it's more solution design than strictly programming, but from your requirements it sounds like you have a good candidate for [HBase](https://hbase.apache.org/) or [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/), or maybe [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/) (though I'm not sure how well MongoDB is optimized for querying a few attributes out of thousands).